# Adding a html file into a c# email app

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("192.168.1.12", 25);


        using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
        {
            msg.From = new MailAddress("noreply@test.com");
            msg.Subject = "***Dexter DB***";

            msg.Body = "***DB backup done***"; // I want to change this so i can do this in html file - how do i pick up this file and send a html form?

            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("test@test.com"));
            client.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: then how do i add call the file?

Comment: like that: msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\windows\win.ini")); Do you want to add a html attachment or have a html formatted mail message ?

Comment: so set the property to true as I've mentioned above. Then in the msg.Body property write a html code

Comment: I was use a test.html file outside of the app so it needs to able to read the test.html file.

Comment: so open that file and read it to a string object: using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
            {
                string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

Comment: You have to read the HTML code stored in that file (test.html) The code is above. Then set msg.Body = str;

Answer (score 0):

Construct a [Mulipart Mime Message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions), using the  [`System.Net.Mail.Attachment` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment).
The part containing HTML has a [mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type) of `text/html`.
You can modify the example on the [reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment) to specify a part without disposition and filename.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

```
msg.Body = File.ReadAllText("c:\\temp\\somefile.html");
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

However, if this page has a HTML form in it, it may not work in some mail clients, as some mail clients strip this functionality from the mail before it is displayed to the recipient.